# Typescript Dynamically Check if value is of a Union Type

Tags: typescript, typechecking, union-types

I have generated a Union type of my supported methods and I want to check that the method is one of my supported methods and then dynamically call the method.
I know that I can check this by using an array of supported methods names and using methods like includes but I'm wondering if it is possible with type checking or not?

```
import * as mathFn from './formula/math';
type SupportedMathFunction = keyof typeof mathFn;
//'fnA'| 'fnB' | ...
```

for example I want to use syntax like:

```
if( methodName is SupportedMathFunction){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Typescript's types do not exist at runtime; your problem needs to be solved in JavaScript land, and then Typescript is just for checking that the solution is OK at compile-time. In this case your union type comes from an object's keys, so check whether the string is a key in that object at runtime.

Comment: it is only possible to do on the type level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check if given method name is a key of mathFn. Unfortunatly, the check is not enough for the compiler to notice that the string is of type SupportedMathFunction , you need to use [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```
function isMemberOfMathFn(methodName: string): methodName is keyof typeof mathFn {
  return methodName in mathFn;
}


function test(methodName: string) {
  if (isMemberOfMathFn(methodName)) {
    const method = mathFn[methodName];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lesiak. I think your solution does the job with the similar syntax which I was looking for.